# Hibernate mapping problems

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class users and frienship

```
users.java


package schema;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

import edu.usc.bg.base.ByteIterator;
import edu.usc.bg.base.ObjectByteIterator;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class users {

        @Id
        private Integer userid=-1;

        private String username;
        private String pw;
        private String fname;
        private String lname;
        private String gender;
        private String dob;
        private String jdate;
        private String ldate;
        private String address;
        private String email;
        private String tel;



        @Column(name="pic")
        @Lob
        private byte[] pic;

        @Column(name="tpic")
        @Lob
        private byte[] tpic;




        //if only entry in friend1 means pending request
        @OneToMany(mappedBy="user1",orphanRemoval=true,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        private Set<friendship>pendingFriendList=new HashSet<>();


        //if entry for user in friend2 too then confirm friends
        @OneToMany(mappedBy="user2",orphanRemoval=true,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        private Set<friendship>confirmedFriendList=new HashSet<>();

}
```

Here, in the friendship class I have two columns each taking two user objects in reference

friendhsip.java

```
package schema;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@IdClass(Pk.class)
@Table(name="friendship")
public class friendship implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="inviterid",referencedColumnName="userid")
    public users user1;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="inviteeid",referencedColumnName="userid")
    public users user2;

    private int status=1;


    public users getUser1() {
        return user1;
    }
    public void setUser1(users user1) {
        this.user1 = user1;
    }
    public users getUser2() {
        return user2;
    }
    public void setUser2(users user2) {
        this.user2 = user2;
    }


    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }


}
```

But the problem is when I add a friendship object to say "PendingFriendList" for a particular user object the same thing gets added to the "ConfirmedFriendList" of that object. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that makes sense. You have a @OneToMany from friend to frienship twice - pending and confirmed - however there is no mechanism in place to restrict the elements in the pending list to the relevant entries and the same for confirmed and that is why you get the same records in both.

There are various solutions.

Two you could take a look at:

One, use the Hibernate (non JPA complaint) @Where annotation on each collection

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user2",orphanRemoval=true,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@Where("where status = xyz")
private Set<friendship>confirmedFriendList=new HashSet<>();
```

Two, use join tables with a different join table for each collection:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user2",orphanRemoval=true,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable("....")
private Set<friendship>confirmedFriendList=new HashSet<>();
```

p.s. In java class names always begin with Upper-Case letters.